# Kernel keeps dying Jupyter, Anaconda. Trying to implement Coreference Resolution using neuralcoref

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter-notebook, spacy

I need to implement a solution which can recognize pronouns associated with the noun in a sentence. Say I have an paragraph about a person, I wanna count how many times the person has been referenced (name or any other pronoun). I want to implement this is Python.

After some research I came across neuralcoref and though it could be useful. After several attempts I'm still getting stuck because the kernel keeps dying.

It would be great if someone can help with this problem. I am also open to suggestions about other libraries/resources I could use to implement this.

Thanks!

This is the code I used:

```
import neuralcoref
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
coref = neuralcoref.NeuralCoref(nlp.vocab)
nlp.add_pipe(coref, name = 'neuralcoref')
doc = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him')
```

Comment: what version of spaCy do you have installed?

Comment: I have spaCy version 2.3.1
But i tried downgrading it to 2.1.0 and got the same error.

Comment: Show your error message in full and your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use spaCy version `2.1.0` and python version `3.7` for neuralcoref to work. See [here](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/issues/197#issuecomment-655191198) for reference